# How can i upload file with rename?

Tags: php

I have a file uploading code. everything is ok but i want to rename the file when it up loaded. my code is here. i need only the rename function and where it should be put. this code is very long because there crop the big image to small.

example: if file is 10MB it will be 40 or 50 KB

```
error_reporting(0);
$change = "";
$abc = "";
define("MAX_SIZE", "400");

function getExtension($str) {
    $i = strrpos($str, ".");
    if (!$i) {
        return "";
    } $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str, $i + 1, $l);
    return $ext;
}

$errors = 0;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $image = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    if ($image) {
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
        if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {
            $change = '<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension</div>';
            $errors = 1;
        } else {
            $size = filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            if ($size > MAX_SIZE * 1024) {
                $change = '<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div>';
                $errors = 1;
            } if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg") {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
            } else if ($extension == "png") {
                $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
            } else {
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
            } echo $scr;
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadedfile);
            $newwidth = 280;
            $newheight = ($height / $width) * $newwidth;
            $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
            imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
            $filename = "../adimages/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
            imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 100);
            imagedestroy($src);
            imagedestroy($tmp);
            imagedestroy($tmp1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use move_uploaded_file() function to rename file. Ref:http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just use the name you want instead of `$_FILES['file']['name']`

For example:

```
$filename = "../adimages/". time();
```

This will name each uploaded file with the current timestamp.

Comment: yes it's works but extension is lost. when i see the folder it shows me only white file without extension but in the browser it display the image.

Comment: Yes, in this case the extension is lost, but you can get the original extension with: `pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Answer (score 0):

change Your below line

```
$filename = "../adimages/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

with the below:-

```
$new_name = "new_file_name".time();
$filename = "../adimages/" . $new_name;
```

**time()** is added for uniqueness. and at the place of **new_file_name** , You can also put **$_FILES['file']['name']**;

Answer (score 0):

try this -- 
just replace your line

```
$filename = "../adimages/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

with this new line

```
$filename = "../adimages/" .time().'.'.$extension ;
```

Comment: yes i got it with extension but without dot. and it doesn't display in image viewer. the file like that 87268728jpg

Comment: ohho image missing now. no image upload

Comment: check your $tmp variable value ?, otherwise you have to use move_uploaded_file() function instead of imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 100); function.